# How to fetch facebook friends via RPXNow with the PLUS membership

Tags: facebook, rpxnow

Now We're capable of fetching the profile from facebook to sign in with it.

Now we want to fetch all friends from facebook to check if they are already on our site, but we can only fetch the friends' id as a list.

Is there any way to implement that?